# NavigationDrawer not working with BottomAppBar

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to use a BottomAppBar, but when I try to show the NavigationView it does not work. I have read about showing NavigationView in BottomAppBar and there are 3 main steps:

1- setSupportActionBar() - In the Activity/Oncreate method

2- set up your menu in  onCreateOptionsMenu

3- catch the listener and show the menu in onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?)

Here is my Activity Code:

class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    setSupportActionBar(bottom_app_bar)

}

override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    when(view!!.id){

    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
      val inflater = menuInflater
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu)
      return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when (item!!.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            val bottomNavDrawerFragment = BottomNavigationDrawerFragment()
            bottomNavDrawerFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, bottomNavDrawerFragment.tag)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

}

And Fragment menu code:

class BottomNavigationDrawerFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_navigation_drawer, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        // Bottom Navigation Drawer menu item clicks
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            // R.id.nav1 -> context!!.toast(getString(R.string.nav1_clicked))
        }
        // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
        // For example, swap UI fragments here
        true
    }
    close_imageview.setOnClickListener {
        this.dismiss()
    }

    disableNavigationViewScrollbars(navigation_view)
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog

    dialog.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
        val d = dialog as BottomSheetDialog

        val bottomSheet = d.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout?
        val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet!!)
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object: BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                if (slideOffset > 0.5) {
                    close_imageview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    close_imageview.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                when (newState) {
                }
            }
        })
    }

    return dialog
}

private fun disableNavigationViewScrollbars(navigationView: NavigationView?) {
    val navigationMenuView = navigationView?.getChildAt(0) as NavigationMenuView
    navigationMenuView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
}
```

}

Anybody have any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: are you housing fragments in an activity and using the bottom bar or navigation to switch between the fragments?

Comment: No, just an an activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the order in the xml and it works.

activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
app:hideOnScroll="true"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_anadir"
app:tint="@null"
app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@drawable/shape_coordinator"
>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">




</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
tools:ignore="PrivateResource"
app:layout_behavior="">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```